# java, JList location

Tags: java, jlist

im stuck here, but what dosnt i cant move JList in Layout to left-top-corner.Im trying to move list to left-top-corner with `list.setLocation();` but seem that is not work it good. Thank you!

```
public class JList_ extends JFrame {
    private JList list;
    private static String[] colorname = {"black", "blue", "red", "white"};
    private static Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.RED,
            Color.WHITE};

    public JList_() {
        super("titile");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        list = new JList(colorname);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setLocation();

        add(new JScrollPane(list));


        list.addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() {
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

                        getContentPane().setBackground(colors[list.getSelectedIndex()]);

                    }

                }

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the alignment in your layout to LEFT.

```
 layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
```

A complete working example using your code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class ListLocation extends JFrame {

    private JList<String> list;
    private static String[] colorname = {"black", "blue", "red", "white"};
    private static Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.WHITE};

    public ListLocation() {
        super("title");

        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);

        list = new JList<String>(colorname);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        setLayout(layout);
        add(list);

        list.addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                getContentPane().setBackground(colors[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
            }
        }
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 800);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new ListLocation();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

More info about `FlowLayout` in [How to Use FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `setLocation()` function takes two integers as an argument. try `list.setLocation(0,0)` Another overloaded function takes a `Point` object as an argument. It places the component at the specified location of the parent.

Also, you're placing the `JList` in a `JScrollPane` and adding it to the frame. So try creating a separate object for the `JScrollPane` and then setting its location to 0,0.

```
JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
add(myScrollPane);
myScrollPane.setLocation(0,0);
```

the above snippet should work for you.

Comment: I did try it, but is from some reason doesnt work it.
I didt try to put list.setLocation(0,0); not work it , it is JList as same place i frame.
Then i try youre code and agein in is same place. Maybe is wrong nothing with java. Im trying to learn it java from thenewboston Bucky, hes great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setLayout(null) for JFrame. Then you can use setBounds() method to set list location on JFrame any where as per your need.

Comment: That may work. Maybe you can provide a working example of the code?

Comment: Yes im trying now, thank you for trying answer my question!